# javascript - localize numbers mapped from server

Tags: javascript, localization

My IIS and client are on different machines and in different regions, so I have to render numbers pushed by IIS as per the client's locale.

I have the following code:

```
<div><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Page, "SomeNumber")%></div>

public double SomeNumber { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SomeNumber = 123456789.123456;
}
```

How can I get IE 8 to render `SomeNumber` as per current locale settings?

If I have a number in javascript then I can render it as per current locale as follows:

```
var number = 123456.789;
alert(number.toLocaleString());
```

I am not using any JS library, please provide pure javascript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

```
function localizeFloat(e) {
            var n = parseFloat(e);
            var localeNumber = n.toLocaleString();
            return localeNumber;
        }

<div>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    document.write(localizeFloat('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.Page, "SomeNumber")%>'));
  </script>
</div>
```